# jQuery autocomplete shows the same results

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery for autocomplete over a big array of data. My code is in this snippet:

```
$( function() {
  $( ".postal-code-autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
      source: postal_codes,
      minLength: 3,
  });
});
```

However when the autocomplete is done and I have my result back, it still shows a number of records with the same value, the one  I was looking for, as shown in the picture: [image]

I would like this drop down list with the same results not to be appearing when my result is found.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:** If I `console.log(postal_codes)`  I get the following results

```
(54767) ["15354", "13341", "13675", "13451", "17455", "15127", "15562", "14561", "13671", "12241", "13451", "15341", "13561", "17341", "17343", "12244", "15349", "13343", "16452", "16672", "16673", "15235", "16233", "15354", "16777", "14122", "13122", "13231", "13121", "13123", "17778", "17676", "13451", "14562", "14123", "15124", "15127", "14671", "15236", "17121", "14342", "15451", "12134", "12132", "15121", "15237", "12462", "15232", "15561", "15562", "15452", "12351", "15341", "13561", "12244", "13341", "16452", "13671", "15235", "16233", "16777", "15772", "14122", "13122", "13451", "14562", "14123", "15124", "15127", "14231", "15236", "14342", "15451", "17563", "15236", "12136", "12461", "13231", "15121", "15237", "15452", "13451", "16777", "13342", "16122", "17121", "16342", "16777", "16777", "15773", "16777", "15773", "15772", "13122", "10431", "10432", "10433", "10434", "11251", "16452"…]
```

Comment: what does postal codes look like? Are you sure it isn't that value repeated? Do a `console.log(postal_codes)` in you web developer console and inspect the results.

Comment: Please share what you are receiving in postal_code.

Comment: console.log(postal_codes)  gives me back an array of the values of my postal codes

Comment: @stefanos array with unique values or repeated data that you are searching for??

Comment: @Shiladitya array with unique values

Comment: Your data is repeating in the array. Remove the duplicates and then push the data to autocomplete. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Askwb/

Comment: Huh.!!  Indeed there were multiple values inside the array and I sorted them with this function. Then in the autocomplete I used: source: unique(postal_codes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very handy jQuery function .uniqueSort() that you can call on an array to sort it and remove duplicate elements.

Try setting `source: $.uniqueSort(postal_codes)`